# Visual Studio Source Control / Version Control, Vault vs Git(hub) vs SVN - lone developer, best option?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, version-control

Visual Studio 2012 Express, SQL Server 2012 Express, MVC 4, Code First

I'm looking for a good single user source control solution.

Vault vs Git(hub) vs SVN

From what I've read deployment should happen FROM the source control server, not separately from VS, right? Can Web Deploy be used FROM a source control server?

What would be the best, most cost effective, simplest, easiest Source Control solution? I used SVN a few years ago and it was pretty clunky.

Visual Studio integration is preferred.

There seem to be mixed opinions on how suitable Github would be (very little integration with VS 2012 Express I think?!).

Cloud option would be good to have. Is there a cloud solution that can automatically deploy direct to production server?

(I guess I'm talking about Constant Integration here - though I have zero experience with it, the principle seems like a good one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Express won't support plug-ins, so integration with VS would not be possible AFAIK. Try Tortoise/SVN which integrates with Windows Explorer instead.

For VS 2012 you could use the express edition of Microsoft TFS, which includes version control and a couple other nice perks, more aimed at team dev though.

Comment: So in that scenario, I would just manuall build in VS - then swich to explorer and deploy from there?

Does Tortoise/SVN provide any cloud infrastructure - and can I deploy directly from it? (Using FTP / Web Deploy)? What is the normal process?

Comment: I was under the impression that you can use TFS Express with VS Express

Comment: Tortoise is a SVN client. Your server could very well be online, doesn't matter. Try Unfuddle.com.

Comment: I assume TSF Express is going to be far better than any of the competition - only issue being if your team gets bigger than 5, but for me that isn't a problem currently.

Comment: Actually it does integrate with VS 2012 Express - I'm still on 2010 and you can't use R# with 2010 express I assumed 2012 would be the same. But yeah TFS express should rock your boat just fine!

Comment: Mike I'd like to give you the answer - otherwise I'll just mark this one - thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Git can now integrate with Visual Studio:

Download here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

Getting Started guide here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx

Comment: I don't think that works with VS 2012 Express - however there is an Express version of TFS now which supports GIT so I'm sure one way or another it can do it

Comment: I just tried installing it and it appears its already installed (perhaps with TFS Express that's installed)

Comment: Yep, Visual Studio 2012 Express works with TFS Express 2012, which can integrate with GIT

Comment: +1 for the links. Smartphone-posting makes that quite painful :)

Answer (score 2):

GIT is your best option.

- Integrates with Visual Studio 2012 using the [Visual Studio Tools for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c)
- There are some great Graphical Clients like [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) and [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)
- Microsoft Team Foundation Server now integrates with Git for automatic deployments with just a Git Push. Scott Hanselman has some great blog posts on how to achieve this [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx), [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingAWebsiteToAzureWhileAddingContinuousDeploymentFromGit.aspx) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WindowsAzureNoKidding.aspx)

Anyways I would strongly recommend taking the free tutorial on Git by Code School http://try.github.io/ (don't be afraid of the command line :P)

Comment: Thanks - so I can deploy directly from Git to my server using Web Deploy (or FTP) - automatically?

As I'm using VS Express - I think I'd use TFS Express. Is it better to use TSF with Git - or the TFS version control (I forget its name)? They basically do the same thing right?

Comment: I don't know about integration with Express. But I know that you can configure either a Git Push with deploy using the build server or you can use the publish option that comes with VS